# SQL Server Web Synchronization - replisapi?diag won't run - just tries to download

Tags: sql-server-2008, web, merge, synchronization, replication

I'm trying to set up SQL Server 2008 Web synchronisation between 2 servers, and am following the instructions step by step on MSDN, here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714039.aspx

All has gone fine, until I get to the section "Testing the Connection to replisapi.dll
" - when I go to `https://my-server-name/sqlreplication/replisapi.dll?diag`, I get a user name and password prompt, which is fine, and a 'There is a problem with this website's security certificate', which I expect, as I'm using a self-signed certificate during development.

Next though, I expect to see a diagnostics page, but instead, I get the browser's generic 'Do you want to open or save replisapi' message, forcing me to either open or save it.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The .dll file is getting downloaded?

This happened to me before.  I had to repair my IIS mappings using the Aspnet_regiis.exe utility.  After running this utility I was able to view the diagnostics page.

http://www.idautomation.com/kb/aspx_error.html

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q306005&GSSNB=1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Brandon,  

Running aspnet_regiis.exe kept telling me that "ASP.NET setup custom actions has stopped working"

However, the fact that you pointed out that this is indeed a mappings problem made me think that I should check the Handler Mappings again, and I can find the problem there.

Replisapi is in the Handler Mappings section, but 'disabled', even though it is set to 'execute' in the access restrictions section. I removed it, and re-added it, and it became 'enabled', but still had the same downloading problem. Restarting IIS, and it's set back to disabled again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Issue: 32 bit applications are disabled in your App pool.

Solution: To resolve the issue click on Application pools, right click on your Application Pool and select Advance Settings. Set "Enable 32 bit Applications" to be "True". Lastly "Stop" and "Start" Application Pool Tasks.